# How to make a pdf document unique?

Tags: php, security, pdf, document, tcpdf

I am developping a web app which generates questions of a trial. So security is very important in the project. When the draw of the question for the trial is done then the app creates a pdf document of it. And I write an encrypted string at the footer of the document :

```
public function Footer() 
{

    if ($this->logo != null) {

        $this->Image($this->logo, 20, 278, 10, 10, 'PNG', '', 'C', false, 200, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);

    }


    $this->SetY(-20);


    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);


    $this->Cell(0, 20, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');

    $this->Cell(0, 20, date("d/m/Y"), 0, 0, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');

    if ( $this->text_crypter != null ) { // this is the encrypted string


        $this->SetY(-7);

        $this->SetFont('helvetica', '', 6);
        $this->MultiCell(0, 7, $this->text_crypter, false, 'L', false, 0, '', '', true);

    }

}
```

As you can see the encrypted string is written at the footer of each page.

[image]

But it is not enough to **uniquely identify** that the document was built from my app because there may be malicious persons who may copy the encrypted string and paste it to another document.

So what are the means to make a pdf document to be proven that it comes from my app ?

Comment: Sign it with a digital signature using a private key only available to your app.

Comment: Lock the pdf with a masterpw that only you know. someone can then still copy the ID string out, but since the pdf's locked with your master pw, there's no way (if you keep the pw secret/secure) to replicate that.

Comment: @pheromix "how to do that" - I'm not proficient with PHP PDF signing libraries, I would know options in the Java or .Net contexts.

Comment: Just look at [Example 052 : digital signature certification](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_052/).

Comment: The signature contains a hash of the PDF document as well as the other details. When it is checked - the documents hash is checked as well. It is not possible to transfer a signature to a different document. The check is certain to fail.

Comment: how to check it ?

Comment: @pheromix *how to check it ?* - Manually you can check it in Adobe Reader. Verify that indeed your certificate is the signer certificate.

Comment: How it works: [digital signature tutorial](http://www.youdzone.com/signature.html). Also [Cryptography Digital signatures](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cryptography/cryptography_digital_signatures.htm).

Answer (score 2):

*(collected from the comments to the question...)*

*To uniquely identify that the document was built from your app,* you should make your application sign the document with a digital signature using a private key only available to your app.

Álvaro González pointed towards [Example 052 : digital signature certification](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_052/) as an example on how to apply a digital signature using TCPDF.

Ryan Vincent explained that the signature contains a hash of the PDF document as well as the other details. When it is checked - the documents hash is checked as well. It is not possible to transfer a signature to a different document. The check is certain to fail.

You can check an integrated PDF signature in Adobe Reader. Verify that indeed your certificate is the signer certificate in the signature verification dialog.

Ryan Vincent pointed to the [digital signature](http://www.youdzone.com/signature.html) and [Cryptography Digital signatures](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cryptography/cryptography_digital_signatures.htm) tutorial for information on how digital signatures work in general.

For details on integrated PDF signatures in particular have a look at [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) on Information Security Stack Exchange and the documents referenced from there.